# MySQL date interval on select

Tags: mysql, sql, intervals

i've made this SQL code :

```
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
    `id_log` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `data_log` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_log`),
)
```

i made it to Insert a record when my server goes down,but i would like to make some check if it wasn't Inserted the same record 10 minutes before.

So i was looking for some **SELECT** that shows only records from **NOW()** to 10 minutes before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `INTERVAL # [UNIT]`, there's various ways to use it -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM logs
 WHERE data_log > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the count of records written to the log in the last ten minutes:

```
SELECT Count(*) as count_in_last_10 FROM logs WHERE data_log BETWEEN DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND NOW()
```